# Hover over a dot for a popup image

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover

I recently downloaded a template code from amcharts.com so that I could put a map on my website. The code puts little pulsating dots on whatever location I set the latitude and longitude, and I can also include a title for each dot. However whenever I try to add another parameter, like a URL, I get an error. At this point I am trying to make it so that the mouse hovering over each dot will create a popup image of that location. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the popup to work, and to make sure that each dot has a different popup image. Here is a link to the codepen I've been using.

https://codepen.io/ZoeyEllen/pen/yvXvZX?editors=1111

I have done quite a bit of googling and I've found several different suggestions for javascript, html, and css, but nothing I've tried seems to have worked. Here is the code that I have so far:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "projection": "mercator",

  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 5,
    "selectedScale": 5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e"
  },

  "areasSettings": {
    "unlistedAreasColor": "#15A892"
  },

  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "images": [ {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Hawaii, USA",
      "latitude": 19.8968,
      "longitude": -155.5828
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Galápagos Islands",
      "latitude": -0.8675,
      "longitude": -89.4364
   }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Italy",
      "latitude": 41.9028,
      "longitude": 12.4964
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Greece",
      "latitude": 37.9838,
      "longitude": 23.7275
      }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "The Bahamas",
      "latitude": 24.9314,
      "longitude": -76.1900
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "South Florida, USA",
      "latitude": 26.1224,
      "longitude": -80.1373
        }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Canada",
      "latitude": 45.5017,
      "longitude": -73.5673
          }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Washington State, USA",
      "latitude": 47.6062,
      "longitude": -122.3321
      }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "California, USA",
      "latitude": 34.0522,
      "longitude": -118.2437
          }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Illinois, USA",
      "latitude": 41.8781,
      "longitude": -87.6298
        }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Costa Rica",
      "latitude": 9.7489,
      "longitude": -83.7534
           }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "North Carolina, USA",
      "latitude": 35.7596,
      "longitude": -79.0193
    } ]
  }
} );

// add events to recalculate map position when the map is moved or zoomed
map.addListener( "positionChanged", updateCustomMarkers );

// this function will take current images on the map and create HTML elements for them
function updateCustomMarkers( event ) {
  // get map object
  var map = event.chart;

  // go through all of the images
  for ( var x in map.dataProvider.images ) {
    // get MapImage object
    var image = map.dataProvider.images[ x ];

    // check if it has corresponding HTML element
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof image.externalElement )
      image.externalElement = createCustomMarker( image );

    // reposition the element accoridng to coordinates
    var xy = map.coordinatesToStageXY( image.longitude, image.latitude );
    image.externalElement.style.top = xy.y + 'px';
    image.externalElement.style.left = xy.x + 'px';
  }
}

// this function creates and returns a new marker element
function createCustomMarker( image ) {
  // create holder
  var holder = document.createElement( 'div' );
  holder.className = 'map-marker';
  holder.title = image.title;
  holder.style.position = 'absolute';

  // maybe add a link to it?
  if ( undefined != image.url ) {
    holder.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = image.url;
    };
    holder.className += ' map-clickable';
  }

  // create dot
  var dot = document.createElement( 'div' );
  dot.className = 'dot';
  holder.appendChild( dot );

  // create pulse
  var pulse = document.createElement( 'div' );
  pulse.className = 'pulse';
  holder.appendChild( pulse );

  // append the marker to the map container
  image.chart.chartDiv.appendChild( holder );
holder.onmouseover = function(){
     console.log(image.title);
  }

  return holder;
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.map-marker {
    /* adjusting for the marker dimensions
    so that it is centered on coordinates */
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.map-marker.map-clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pulse {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #FFB6C1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ff69b4;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
  }
.map-marker .dot {
    border: 3px solid #ff69b4;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes pulse {
   0% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
   25% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.1;
   }
   50% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
      opacity: 0.3;
   }
   75% {
      -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
      opacity: 0.5;
   }
   100% {
      -moz-transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
   25% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 0.1;
   }
   50% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
      opacity: 0.3;
   }
   75% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
      opacity: 0.5;
   }
   100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 0.0;
   }
    
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Use external JavaScript, but take a look at that Marker [click](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple) Event.

Comment: a little late, but i hope it is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i hope this is what you are looking for. I added the pop ups to appear center in the map. You can add yor css for the pop up but this demostrates what you want.

**Explanation**

> HTML

Added each popup as a `<div>` at the bottom of the HTML. They have the individual value to refer in the images objects ant their class `popup` to give the the style you want

```
<div id="pop0" class="popup">A</div>
```

> CSS

Added two clases

1. popup: to style the popups as a whole

   .popup {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     margin: auto;
     background: red;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
   }
2. popon: to turn the popup on with the listeners

   .popon {
     display: block;
   }

> JS

Added two diferent thing here

First I added the `pop` value in each element to refer to the `id` of the desired popup for each dot

Second I added two events listeners

1. MouseOver - This will add the class `popon` to the popup element of the dot

   holder.onmouseover = function() {
       popup.classList.add('popon');
     }
2. MouseLeave - This will remove the class `popon` to the popup element of the dot

   holder.onmouseleave = function() {
       popup.classList.remove('popon');
     }

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "projection": "mercator",

  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 5,
    "selectedScale": 5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e"
  },

  "areasSettings": {
    "unlistedAreasColor": "#15A892"
  },

  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "images": [{
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Hawaii, USA",
      "latitude": 19.8968,
      "longitude": -155.5828,
      "pop": "pop0"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Galápagos Islands",
      "latitude": -0.8675,
      "longitude": -89.4364,
      "pop": "pop1"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Italy",
      "latitude": 41.9028,
      "longitude": 12.4964,
      "pop": "pop2"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Greece",
      "latitude": 37.9838,
      "longitude": 23.7275,
      "pop": "pop3"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "The Bahamas",
      "latitude": 24.9314,
      "longitude": -76.1900,
      "pop": "pop4"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "South Florida, USA",
      "latitude": 26.1224,
      "longitude": -80.1373,
      "pop": "pop5"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Canada",
      "latitude": 45.5017,
      "longitude": -73.5673,
      "pop": "pop6"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Washington State, USA",
      "latitude": 47.6062,
      "longitude": -122.3321,
      "pop": "pop7"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "California, USA",
      "latitude": 34.0522,
      "longitude": -118.2437,
      "pop": "pop8"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Illinois, USA",
      "latitude": 41.8781,
      "longitude": -87.6298,
      "pop": "pop9"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "Costa Rica",
      "latitude": 9.7489,
      "longitude": -83.7534,
      "pop": "pop10"
    }, {
      "zoomLevel": 5,
      "scale": 0.5,
      "title": "North Carolina, USA",
      "latitude": 35.7596,
      "longitude": -79.0193,
      "pop": "pop11"
    }]
  }
});


// add events to recalculate map position when the map is moved or zoomed
map.addListener("positionChanged", updateCustomMarkers);

// this function will take current images on the map and create HTML elements for them
function updateCustomMarkers(event) {
  // get map object
  var map = event.chart;

  // go through all of the images
  for (var x in map.dataProvider.images) {
    // get MapImage object
    var image = map.dataProvider.images[x];

    // check if it has corresponding HTML element
    if ('undefined' == typeof image.externalElement)
      image.externalElement = createCustomMarker(image);

    // reposition the element accoridng to coordinates
    var xy = map.coordinatesToStageXY(image.longitude, image.latitude);
    image.externalElement.style.top = xy.y + 'px';
    image.externalElement.style.left = xy.x + 'px';
  }
}

// this function creates and returns a new marker element
function createCustomMarker(image) {
  // create holder
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.className = 'map-marker';
  holder.title = image.title;
  holder.style.position = 'absolute';

  // maybe add a link to it?
  if (undefined != image.url) {
    holder.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = image.url;
    };
    holder.className += ' map-clickable';
  }

  // create dot
  var dot = document.createElement('div');
  dot.className = 'dot';
  holder.appendChild(dot);

  // create pulse
  var pulse = document.createElement('div');
  pulse.className = 'pulse';
  holder.appendChild(pulse);

  // append the marker to the map container
  image.chart.chartDiv.appendChild(holder);


  //Mouseover listener
  var popup = document.getElementById(image.pop);
  holder.onmouseover = function() {
    popup.classList.add('popon');
  }
  holder.onmouseleave = function() {
    popup.classList.remove('popon');
  }

  return holder;
}
```

```css
  #chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.map-marker {
  /* adjusting for the marker dimensions
    so that it is centered on coordinates */
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.map-marker.map-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pulse {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #FFB6C1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ff69b4;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

.map-marker .dot {
  border: 3px solid #ff69b4;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.popon {
  display: block;
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="pop0" class="popup">A</div>
<div id="pop1" class="popup">B</div>
<div id="pop2" class="popup">C</div>
<div id="pop3" class="popup">D</div>
<div id="pop4" class="popup">E</div>
<div id="pop5" class="popup">F</div>
<div id="pop6" class="popup">G</div>
<div id="pop7" class="popup">H</div>
<div id="pop8" class="popup">I</div>
<div id="pop9" class="popup">J</div>
<div id="pop10" class="popup">K</div>
<div id="pop11" class="popup">L</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That looks like it should work perfectly. The one remaining question I have is where exactly to put the image I want to use in the html. Where do I plug in the source of the image to get it to pop up properly? (Forgive me, I know very little about code, I am a blogger not a coder, but I want to learn!)

Comment: @ZoeyBest i dont really know what image you are refering, but we can do 1 of 3 things. 1) Edit your question and add what else you are refferring to. Comment when you do so i can notice it. This is not the best as having multiple different questions in a single SO posting might be bad. 2) Add another question with the next fase of the code and comment the lin k here so i can go and help you. 3) We can close this question and schedule a skype call so i can help you with your code. If you decide one of these things let me know, I am more than happy to help you.

Comment: @ZoeyBest pliss dont forget to upvote or close the question if my answer help you. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Let me see if I can clarify my question. Let's say I would like this image to be the image that pops up for "pop0." http://assets.natgeotv.com/Photos/56/140469.jpg Where do I enter that link into the html? Thank you!

Comment: @ZoeyBest what i made is a div for each dot. You can just treat each div as a pop up. You can add text and images to it. Maybe you should close this question as i allready anser the question. And make another one to get the popup you want to make. I will love to help in the other question if you post the link in a comment

Comment: @ZoeyBest thank you, pliss dont forget to upvote if you can.